# Continuous function and closed kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

My teacher said the if $f$ is continuous then $ker(f)$ is closed but the opposite is not true and an example of this is $X=C^1[0,1]$, $Y=C[0,1]$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$.  My question is how does this example show that closed $ker(f)$ doesn't imply that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Where is the example? What is $f$?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval, $f(\psi)=\frac{d\psi}{dx}$

Comment: And what are the topologies on both spaces?

Comment: @gbd: You forgot to say what $f$ is in your question, but you can still edit.

Answer (score 0):

As implied in my comment, the issue here is what topologies you take on both spaces. As we seek a counter example for continuity, it makes sense to choose a strong topology on $Y$ and a weak topology on $X$. So, let us consider $X=C^1[0,1]$ with the product topology and $Y=C[0,1]$ with the topology induced by the supremum norm. Your job is to show that the set of constant functions is closed in the product topology, and that your operator is not continuous.